# $dbclass->real_escape_string not working

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I have two classes which are below:

```
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$country=$_POST['Countryname'];
echo $gender;// display return
$gender = $dbclass->real_escape_string($gender);
$gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);
echo $gender;//Nothing returns
```

and a `db.class.php`:

```
    <?php

class database {

var $_sql           = '';   
/** @var Internal variable to hold the connector resource */
var $_resource      = '';
/** @var Internal variable to hold the query result*/
var $_result        = ''; 

/**
* Database object constructor
* @param string Database host
* @param string Database user name
* @param string Database user password
* @param string Database name
*/
function database() {
    global $glob;
    $host = $glob['dbhost'];

    $user = $glob['dbusername'];

    $pass = $glob['dbpassword'];
    $db = $glob['dbdatabase'];
    $this->_resource = @mysqli_connect( $host, $user, $pass, $db );
   /** if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    else{
        echo "Could not connect to the database!";
        exit;
    }*/               
}

/**
* Execute the query
* @return mixed A database resource if successful, FALSE if not.
*/
function query($sql) { 
    $_sql = $sql;

    return $_result = @mysqli_query($this->_resource, $_sql);               
}

function fetchArray($result) {
    return @mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}

function fetchAssoc($result) {
    return @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
 function real_escape_string($string) {
    // todo: make sure your connection is active etc.
    return @mysqli_real_escape_string($string);
  }

}
?>
```

Here If I use  `$gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);` nothing return.

Comment: Are you sure that `$_POST['gender']` contains something? And do you probably call it before the connection is established?

Comment: @Nico Hasee-Yep..it will echo value

Comment: Remove the @ sign which ignores error messages, you need to see these and handle them.

Comment: @juvajacob  remove all `@` and check for possible errors.Also before `$gender=$_POST['gender'];` add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` to cehck for possible errors